# For the same use case, is GSI better than LSI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to sort items identified by the same partition key using different sort keys.

In that case, a LSI seems to be the perfect fit, but would I get any benefits by using a GSI instead? *(which would then use the same PK as the table)*. I don't care about consistency *(maybe I should?)* and I'm more focused on flexibility of use and overall price.

Any guidance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pay extra for a GSI, you don't for an LSI.

In addition, as you mentioned a GSI is eventually consistent with the table.

However, a table with LSIs is limited 10GB per partition
See [Quotas - Partition Keys and Sort Keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html#limits-partition-sort-keys)

> In general, there is no practical limit on the number of distinct sort
> key values per partition key value.
>
> The exception is for tables with secondary indexes. With a local
> secondary index, there is a limit on item collection sizes: For every
> distinct partition key value, the total sizes of all table and index
> items cannot exceed 10 GB. This might constrain the number of sort
> keys per partition key value. For more information, see Item
> Collection Size Limit.

The [Item Collection Size limit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LSI.html#LSI.ItemCollections.SizeLimit)

> The maximum size of any item collection is 10 GB. This limit does not
> apply to tables without local secondary indexes. Only tables that have
> one or more local secondary indexes are affected.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, if each of my partitions _(ie everything stored under a given primary key?)_ is less then 10GB I should not have any issues with that limit right?

Comment: @geauser correct.

Comment: @geauser actually, that should be "ie everything stored under a given *partition* key" .  The primary key is the partition key + sort key.

Comment: Yes, good catch, that's what I meant. Thanks for the comment!